# How to set number of ticks in plt.colorbar?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

When I plot a matrix with a colorbar, then the colorbar has 10 ticks. Since the colorbar has to be pretty small, the ticklabels overlap. Therefore I want to reduce the number of ticks from 10 to 5. I do not want to reduce the font size!

Is there an easy way to do this? I do not want to set the ticks manually...

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The [MaxNLocator](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator) ticker might suit your purposes?

> class **matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator**
>
> Select no more than N intervals at nice locations

For example:

```
from matplotlib import ticker

# (generate plot here)
cb = plt.colorbar()
tick_locator = ticker.MaxNLocator(nbins=5)
cb.locator = tick_locator
cb.update_ticks()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was the correct (and very easy) solution!

Comment: At the moment there is no tick at the upper end of the colorbar, but at the lower end. This looks very asymmetric and ugly to me. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: Ok.... just put     cb.ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.AutoLocator())   before c.b.update_icks()

Comment: Thanks @FrankTheTank for the addition. For other people copy and pasting that addition, there's a hidden character which causes a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` on the brackets. Just delete and retype the brackets (and thus deleting also the hidden character) and it'll work fine.

Comment: A simpler option to get ticks at both boundaries is: `LinearLocator(5)`

Comment: @FrankTheTank For adding ticks at the top of the colorbar, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37161022/2005415).

Answer (score 15):

For the record, this is now possible also via:

```py
cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.ax.locator_params(nbins=5)
```

which talks to `ticker.MaxNLocator`.

Comment: This changed the vmin / vmax in my case. `cbar.set_ticks` worked, though.

Comment: @user1834164 how did you apply `cbar.set_ticks`?

Comment: Note that the two solutions above (using cbar.ax.locator_params and ticker) don't seem to be consistent in getting the same results always.
```
from matplotlib import ticker
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
nbins = 5
z = np.random.normal(size=(5,10))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
img = ax.matshow(z, cmap="bwr_r", aspect='auto', vmin=-10, vmax=10)
cbar = fig.colorbar(img)
# tick_locator = ticker.MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins)
# cbar.locator = tick_locator
# cbar.update_ticks()
cbar.ax.locator_params(nbins=nbins)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that the two solutions using cbar.ax.locator_params and ticker don't seem to be consistent in getting the same results always. ticker seems to be consistent in getting the number of bins, while locator_params seems to want  to enforce that the endpoints have ticks (rather than, say a tick mark near the endpoint but not at it).  I am not sure what the difference in behavior is, but suffice it to say they are not identical.  Again, this assumes that you want the number of ticks to be exactly what you specify.  I'd say that if you want to set the number of ticks (but have their positions determined automatically) and want to supply your own different labels, then maybe use ticker to make sure these are consistent (although usually if you supply your own labels you would want the positions to be guaranteed).

```
from matplotlib import ticker
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(4)
nbins = 7

z = np.random.normal(size=(5,10))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
img = ax.matshow(z, cmap="bwr_r", aspect='auto', vmin=-10, vmax=10)
cbar = fig.colorbar(img)
cbar.ax.locator_params(nbins=nbins)
ax.set_title('locator_params')
plt.show() 

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
img = ax.matshow(z, cmap="bwr_r", aspect='auto', vmin=-10, vmax=10)
cbar = fig.colorbar(img)
tick_locator = ticker.MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins)
cbar.locator = tick_locator
cbar.update_ticks()
ax.set_title('ticker')
plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]